# Terraform dynamic variable lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am writing some terraform code that looks up the ami based on a variable called fortios_version.  I seem to not understand how to have a map pass back a map value.  Here is my code...

```
variable "fortios_version" {
  type        = string
}

variable "fortios_map" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "7.2.0" = "fgtvmbyolami-7-2-0"
    "6.4.8" = "fgtvmbyolami-6-4-8"
  }
}

variable "fgtvmbyolami-7-2-0" {
  type = map
  default = {
    us-east-1      = "ami-08a9244de2d3b3cfa"
    us-east-2      = "ami-0b07d15df1781b3d8"
  }
}
```

My aws instance code:

```
ami                     = lookup(lookup(var.fortios_map[var.fortios_version]), var.region)
```

My variable:

```
fortios_version: "7.2.0"
```

I hope I am making sense.   I have played with different variations all day with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically refer to `fgtvmbyolami-7-2-0` based on the output of `fortios_map`. It would be best to re-organize your variables:

```
variable "fortios_version" {
  type        = string
}

variable "fortios_map" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "7.2.0" = "fgtvmbyolami-7-2-0"
    "6.4.8" = "fgtvmbyolami-6-4-8"
  }
}

variable "amis" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "fgtvmbyolami-7-2-0"  =  {
          us-east-1      = "ami-08a9244de2d3b3cfa"
          us-east-2      = "ami-0b07d15df1781b3d8"
        },
    "fgtvmbyolami-6-4-8"  =  {
          us-east-1      = "ami-08a92333cfa"
          us-east-2      = "ami-0b07dgggg781b3d8"
        }        
  }
}
```

then

```
ami  = var.amis[var.fortios_map[var.fortios_version]][var.region]
```

You can expand this to ad `lookup` in to have some default values for each map.

Comment: Additionally, the `amis` map is much more data than an input variable, and as such would probably be relocated to either `locals`, `data.aws_ami`, or external data source by best practices.